# calling OOP PHP function via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, function, oop

I have OOP php file and I would like to call one of the function by AJAX, i have read a lot about this (mostly stackoverflow), but for some reason, it just doesnt work.

I know that ajax function is called (I tried to add some alert into success function and that alert appeared after clicking the button), but somehow it ignores everything from file ajax.php (i even tried to add some echo at the top of ajax.php file, but nothing happened)

also note that I need button, not input (although that would be much easier)

this is my button:

```
<button class='formular-button' type='button' onclick='prihlasPA()'> vypiš přihlaš </button>
```

this is my script for button:

```
<script>
function prihlasPA() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {action: 'prihlasP'},
    success: function(){},
    error: function(){
        alert("chyba");
    }
  });    
}
</script>
```

and this is inside ajax.php, which is called by AJAX:

```
include( 'navstevnik.php' );
echo "aaa";
if(isset($_POST['action']) ) {
    $navstevnik = new navstevnik; //navstevnik is name of my class btw
    $navstevnik->vypisPrihlas();
}
```

I dont think it matters, but in my function vypisPrihlas() is this code:

```
public function vypisPrihlas(){
    $this->index=1;
    echo ' 
        <fieldset class="formular">
        <div class="pure-control-group stred" >
            <input id="nick" type="text" name="nickP" placeholder="Nickname">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group stred">
            <input id="password" type="password" name="hesloP" placeholder="Heslo">
        </div>
        <input class="pure-button pure-button-primary stred" style=width:188px; type="submit" name="buttonP" value="přihlásit" />
    </fieldset>'; 
}
```

Comment: Sure, I dont have experiences with jQuery, but If it can help in this situation, then I would gladly use it.

Comment: You're already using jQuery, unless `$.ajax` is a custom made function.

Comment: Its not custom. I though he meant something different from my solution by that "jQuery solution"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issues with the above code.

When the function `vypisPrihlas` echos the HTML, you won't see it on your main page. Instead, you need to load it in from your success function and append the HTML somewhere on your page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {action: 'prihlasP'},
    success: function(data){
        $( ".your_favorite_div" ).append(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("chyba");
    }
});
```

Comment: I see your point, but when i try that, nothing changes.
I also tried this with simple echo I added to the ajax.php file and that echo appeared, but nothing from vypisPrihlas().

Comment: Do you happen to get the error alert (chyba)? Also, if you check under the Network tab (f12->Network), do you get the expected results from `ajax.php`?

Comment: I didnt get error, but now I tried to append it into different div and this works, dunno exactly why different divs have different outputs, but with some layout adjustment I will be able to do it as I wanted in first place, Im sorry for troubles and thank you a lot for your time, u saved me.

Answer (score 0):

By what you said, the ajax function is fine, right?

I think your problem is the path for PHP, since it is not called. try change this line

```
url: "ajax.php",
```

for the complete path, like \var\www\path_to_code\ajax.php. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but url is actually called correctly, otherwise
error: function() would be called (i tried to remove ajax.php field and error happened)